# php logout fails to log user out of the page they logged out from

Tags: php, logout

I have a PHP site with Login and Logout, using `$_SESSION['userName']` to store the `username` of the logged in member.

The login works, and the logout can log the user out of all pages EXEPT the page the user where on, when they clicked "logout" ... Any ideas?

Here is my Login code and Logout code:

Code:  /login.php

```
session_start();
//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
$host        =    'host';
$user        =    'username';
$password    =    'password';
//=============Data Base Information=================
$database    =    'database';

$conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information 
is not Correct'); //Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

//===============End Server Configuration============

//*******Form Information********

$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$passWord=md5($password); // Encrypted Password

//*********retrieving data from Database**********

$query = "select * from users where userName='$userName' and passWord='$passWord'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

//**********if $userName and $passWord will match database, The above function 
//**********will return 1 row

if($rows==1)

//***if the userName and password matches then register a session and redrect 
//***user to the Successfull.php
{
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
else
{
    echo 'Incorrect username or password.';
}
exit;
```

Code:  /logout.php

```
session_name('userName');
session_start('userName');
session_unset('userName');
session_destroy();
header("Location:index.php");
```

I really hope you can help me with this issue.

Comment: You don't have to provide 'userName' when using `session_start` and `session_unset`

Comment: 1) Start using mysqli http://www.php.net/mysqli
2) You might want to add this, it will reset the session array `$_SESSION = array();`  and ofcourse start page with `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you have a bit of code in your script to check username session is set.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] ='';
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
```